# Javascript - Deeply Filtering The Array

Tags: javascript

I have an object which looks like this for some reason:

```
const obj = [{
    slug: 'something',
    nestedSlug: [{
      slug: 'n1',
      deeplyNestedSlug: [{
          slug: 'n11'
        },
        {
          slug: 'n21'
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    slug: 'nothing',
    nestedSlug: [{
      slug: 'n2',
      deeplyNestedSlug: [{
          slug: 'n12'
        },
        {
          slug: 'n22'
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    slug: 'anything',
    nestedSlug: [{
      slug: 'n3',
      deeplyNestedSlug: [{
          slug: 'n13'
        },
        {
          slug: 'n23'
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
]
```

I want the result something like this: `['n1', 'n22', 'n3']`. And I tried the following:

```js
const requiredItems = ['n1', 'n22', 'n3']
let collection = []
const obj = [{
    slug: 'something',
    nestedSlug: [{
      slug: 'n1',
      deeplyNestedSlug: [{
          slug: 'n11'
        },
        {
          slug: 'n21'
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    slug: 'nothing',
    nestedSlug: [{
      slug: 'n2',
      deeplyNestedSlug: [{
          slug: 'n12'
        },
        {
          slug: 'n22'
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    slug: 'anything',
    nestedSlug: [{
      slug: 'n3',
      deeplyNestedSlug: [{
          slug: 'n13'
        },
        {
          slug: 'n23'
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
]

let parentIndex,
  childIndex

requiredItems.map(x => {
  const grandParent = obj.nestedSlug.findIndex((y, i) => {
    if (y.slug === x) {
      parentIndex = i
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  })

  if (grandParent !== -1) {
    collection.push(obj.nestedSlug[parentIndex])
  } else {
    const children = obj.nestedSlug[i].deeplyNestedSlug.findIndex((z, i) => {
      if (z.slug === x) {
        childIndex = i
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    })

    if (children !== -1) {
      collection.push(obj.nestedSlug[parentIndex].deeplyNestedSlug[childIndex])
    }
  }
})

console.log(collection)
```

...which, of course didn't work at all. Please help!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `["n1", "n2", "n3"]`?

Comment: @LucaKiebel I want `['n1', 'n22', 'n3']` and I am damn sure

Comment: can you explain how it works? how are you choosing when to pick inside deeplyNestedSlug?

Comment: @ChrisLi It's just random. That's the beauty of this question XD. Seriously, btw!

Comment: please use the same name for nested arrays. it it easier to take same named property for searching deeper items.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sure!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = [{"slug":"something","nestedSlug":[{"slug":"n1","deeplyNestedSlug":[{"slug":"n11"},{"slug":"n21"}]}]},{"slug":"nothing","nestedSlug":[{"slug":"n2","deeplyNestedSlug":[{"slug":"n12"},{"slug":"n22"}]}]},{"slug":"anything","nestedSlug":[{"slug":"n3","deeplyNestedSlug":[{"slug":"n13"},{"slug":"n23"}]}]}];

var result = [];
for (data of obj) {
  for (info of data.nestedSlug) {
    if (info.slug == "n2") {
      result.push(info.deeplyNestedSlug[1].slug);
      continue;
    } 
    result.push(info.slug)        
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: But that is what you are getting, an array of `obj.nestedSlug.slug`

Comment: Actually, I just want `['n1', 'n22', 'n3']`. That's why I wrote "Deeply Filtering" in the question

Comment: That's a hacky one, Naruto-kun!

Comment: It's just that I don't want the same result. User will dynamically input and I am gonna output the result. Yours is specific so I am sorry man I wouldn't accept this as answer.

Comment: Well then explain what can change in your object structure

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the same name for the nested arrays, like `nested` for easier access and because this property is known in advance.

Then you could iterate the array of objects at the outer level and check the given `slug` against the object. If equal, assign the object to `result` variable, otherwise try to get the object from `nested`.

Inside of [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), the reuslt is taken as return value for a short circuit.

At the end, return the found result.

```js
function getObject(array, slug) {
    var result;
    array.some(o => result = o.slug === slug && o || getObject(o.nested || [], slug));
    return result;
}

var slugs = ['n1', 'n22', 'n3'],
    data = [{ slug: 'something', nested: [{ slug: 'n1', nested: [{ slug: 'n11' }, { slug: 'n21' }] }] }, { slug: 'nothing', nested: [{ slug: 'n2', nested: [{ slug: 'n12' }, { slug: 'n22' }] }] }, { slug: 'anything', nested: [{ slug: 'n3', nested: [{ slug: 'n13' }, { slug: 'n23' }] }] }],
    collection = slugs.map(getObject.bind(null, data));

console.log(collection);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```